# wget - options to save all new files

Tags: linux

I am attempting to use wget to download all new versions of a single file from a server. The file is updated once an hour at an unspecified and variable time.

I am running a cron script that runs wget every 10 minutes with the -N option to only download the new versions of the file (they all have the same name). However with the -N version the previous file on my RasPi is overwritten so I lose the older versions I need to keep. If I don't use -N I get a new copy every 10 minutes 5 of which are duplicates. Is there an option that will allow wget to download the new versions of the file but not overwrite the old ones ? If not is there an alternative solution ?

Thanks John

Comment: One obvious alternative is to write a script which removes duplicates. Anyway, it doesn't look like your question is about a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of thinking and searching I came up with the following that seems to work Ok. It is rather specific to the folder structure on my Raspberry Pi and to the files I am trying to download but with these changed should be of more general use.

--- shell script ----

```
    #!/bin/sh
```

## change to the data folder

cd ~/Camera_Data/Download

## -N option is supposed to only get new files - only works if file is still in the destination folder at next run of WGET -N

wget -N -a WGETout.log http://oiswww.eumetsat.org/IPPS/html/latestImages/EUMETSAT_MSG_RGBFog_WesternEurope.jpg

## set variable to download filename

latestfile=EUMETSAT_MSG_RGBFog_WesternEurope.jpg

## get checksum of downloaded (latest) file

file1_sha=$( md5sum $latestfile | awk '{print $1}')

## check only files starting with 20 to prevent comparing file EUMETSAT_MSG_RGBFog_WesternEurope.jpg with itself

## Also prevents checking image files which begin with 'IMG*.JPG' in the same folder

for filename in 20*.jpg ; do

## this variable has to be set in the loop

testfile=$filename

## Get checksums of next file

file2_sha=$( md5sum $testfile | awk '{print $1}')
    # Compare the checksums
if [ "x$file1_sha" = "x$file2_sha" ]
    then
    printf "Files %s and %s are the same\n" "$latestfile" "$testfile"
    # current file already exists
    exit 0
    else
    printf "Files %s and %s are different\n" "$latestfile" "$testfile"
fi
done

## executes if no similar files found

printf "No similar files found copy to new name\n"
cp  EUMETSAT_MSG_RGBFog_WesternEurope.jpg "$(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M.jpg")"
exit 0

-- end of script --

The print statements can be removed - they are only there to show it is working.

If you have lots of files in the destination directory it would be better to sort them by latest modification time in the for loop. There are examples of how to do this on the web using 'ls' piped to 'sort' but they did not work for me.

The rejection of files starting with IMG prevents checking the camera image files that get downloaded to the same folder by a python programme. Since there are normally several hundred it provides a performance gain.

I could not get the code block to work so the comments are in in most cases in large bold rather than having the preceding comment #.

Comment: Re the code blocks here: Yes, I've had problems with that also. It seems it's not *exactly* markdown, but a slight variation on it. While "fencing" doesn't seem to work here, I have found that 8 spaces in front of each line of code seems to get the job done.

Comment: Just one other very minor thing: I noticed that you use `_sha` in your variable names. That confused me until I read the code as I thought you were doing SHA instead of MD5.

Comment: @Seamus - that is because I stole that bit of the code from another post - I changed the check to MD5 but left the variable names the same !!

Comment: If anyone wants to see a better formated version of the script(s) they are on my website at www.JohnMurrell.org.uk

Answer (score 2):

It may be possible to use some of the many `wget` options to accomplish your objective, but as I don't use it everyday, I'd have to experiment to provide that answer. But yes, of course there are alternatives - many of them. I'd use a simple shell script were I in your situation, and not intimately familiar with `wget` options; here it is:

1. from the command line, start the `pico` editor, and type the following shell script into it:

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash 
   newfn=$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
   newfn+="TheNewFileName.txt" 
   mv ~/TheOldFileName.txt ~/$newfn
   ```

Note that you have some options: `mv` will rename the existing file. If you'd rather leave the old file in place, use `cp` in place of `mv`. If you want to operate on the files in different folders than `~/` (your home dir), substitute the correct folder names.

The script will take an existing file named "TheOldFileName.txt", and rename it by concatenating the current date time stamp with a string "TheNewFileName", yielding, e.g. "20180614223302TheNewFileName.txt" as the new file name.

2. Save this file as "filenamer.sh", and exit `pico`, and make it executable:

   ```
   chmod 775 filenamer.sh
   ```
3. Add this to your `crontab` to execute when `wget` does.

Let us know if you have questions.

Comment: Thanks Seamus - that is where I got to as well. The problem is as soon as you rename or move the file WGET -N downloaded it 'forgets' that it has downloaded the file already and downloads it again when the script next runs :-( . I have asked the same question on the WGET-bug list to see if they have an answer. If not I may be forced to use one of the programmes or scripts that delete duplicate files that have different names but the same contents.

Comment: OK - simple enough to cure. We'll simply calculate the secure hash for the existing file before we run the remainder of the script. Kinda' busy now, but will post a revision in a day or two.

Comment: Hi @Seamus, I think I have managed to write a shell script that works. All I need to do is to test it tonight. It seems to run ok manually but the real test is when it runs from a cron script. It should only download new files using WGET-N. My script uses the md5 checksum to check if a new version has been downloaded and if so saves it under a date-time similar to your code above. Is it worth posting the code here for others ? It is crude in that it calculates the md5 checksum for all the files every 10 minutes. I will 'answer' my question when the script has been tested.

Comment: Good for you! If it works manually, I can almost guarantee that we'll get it to work under cron - don't worry about that. And wrt posting your code, I think that's a great idea - test it before you post it.